# Writing a script to copy images of certain dimensions

Tags: powershell, scripting

What I'm looking to do is have a script run through a directory of photos (i.e. C:\user\userid\Pictures), including sub-directories, and copy ones that are greater than LxH dimension (i.e. 1920x1080) into another folder (i.e. C:\user\userid\Destination). This is going to be run on a windows machine with over one million photos and over 300 sub-directories in its main folder. Speed isn't an issue to me (anything is faster than going through each sub-directory by hand), so even something that takes literal days to complete this is more than enough.

So the algorithm may look something like this:

```
Function findLargeImages(curr, dest):
    For each file/folder in curr:
        if file:
            if file is image:
                if (image.width >= ####) AND (image.height >= ####)
                    copy image to dest
        else if folder:
            findImage(folder, dest)
    return (the sound of happiness)
```

But I could be completely missing the point of using a scripting language.

I've seen that Powershell has a `Copy-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`, but I wouldn't know how to use those, since my knowledge of Powershell is that it's blue and "replaced" the command line. I lack the knowledge to both safely traverse the file system, and get some sort of property to determine the image height/width.

Powershell is the first thing I came across when I began looking into this, but if it can be run on Windows, then I'll be more than happy. I could easily install most other languages and run that code if needed. If there is some software out there to do this already, then your Google-fu is far greater than mine.

In case I manage to lose my login info, a HUGE thanks to anyone who helps in advance!

Comment: Where's the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the .NET [System.Drawing.Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
$source      = 'C:\user\userid\Pictures'
$destination = 'C:\user\userid\Destination'
$maxWidth    = 1920
$maxHeight   = 1080

# if the destination path does not exist, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

# Add System.Drawing assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # capture the full filename so we can use it in the catch block
    $fileName = $_.FullName
    # Open image file
    try {
        $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($fileName)
        # use '-ge'  if you want to copy files with a width and/or height Greater Or Equal To the max dimensions
        # use '-and' if you want to copy files where both the Width and the Height exceed the max dimensions
        if ($img.Width -gt $maxWidth -or $img.Height -gt $maxHeight) {
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Force
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not open file '$fileName'. Not an image file?"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Theo! As I asked Drew, will having video files in some sub-directories hurt the program? And could I replace `-gt` with `-ge` for a greater-than or equal-to sign, as well as replacing `-or` with `-and`?

Comment: @TheMediocreProgrammer I have added a `try{..} catch{..}` block in the code to skip files that are not images. I also put in some comment about using `-ge` vs. `-gt` and whether you want `-or` or `-and`.

Comment: I works wonderfully. For some reason, though, the warnings do not display the file's name. `WARNING: Could not open file ''. Not an image file?"` pops up fine, but there is no filename given. I tested it on one of the folders, including various subfolders and videos, and it runs quick and effortlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TheMediocreProgrammer Ah yes, sorry, my bad. Inside the `catch{..}` block, the automatic variable `$_` is no longer a FileInfo object, but instead an [ErrorRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6#accessing-exception-information) object. That object of course describes the error that has occurred and does not have a `FullName` property of the file. I have edited my code to capture the filename so we can use it inside the catch block.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to inform you that I thought `$_` was no longer in scope. I ran it overnight, and woke up to a folder of images of suitable size. You saved me literal weeks of work sorting these by hand. I also managed to edit it to allow for files within a date range of my choice. Thank you so much, again!

Comment: @TheMediocreProgrammer Thanks for the nice feedback. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

At least you have the logic in your example. I doubt most people would knock something up for you.

I assume you are unaware of how to write code to the level that is required for this task, please take a moment to learn and understand the below solution. Ask questions if needed.

```
# Parent Directory
$Directory = "C:\user\userid\" 

# This includes any folders with the word Pictures in the file path
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Dir $Directory -Recurse -Include "*Pictures*"
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

Foreach($Folder in $Folders) {
    $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($Folder.FullName)
    Foreach ($file in $objFolder.Items()){

        # Index 31 is the Dimensions in the metadata
        # Splits it as it returns 3880 x 5184 as an example
        $Dimensions = $objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, 31) -split ' x '
        # Index 165 is the Extension in the metadata, e.g. ".JPG"
        $FileType = $objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, 165)

        # If 3880 is greater than or equal to 1920 AND 5184 is greater than or equal to 1080
        If(($Dimensions[0] -ge 1920) -and ($Dimensions[1] -ge 1080) -and ($FileType -in ('.jpg','.png'))) {
            Copy-Item -Path $File.Path -Destination 'C:\user\userid\Destination' 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew! I don't have time to run this yet, but I do have a few questions. I need to scan every single folder, so could I just replace `*Pictures*` with `*` for a general wildcard? Also, some of the folders may have video files as well. Will this hurt the program, or will it not matter since they don't have a Dimension property?

Comment: To include all subfolders of the `$Directory`, remove `-Include "*Pictures*"`. I have updated the code so you can include file types.