# Powershell "Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" in ForEach-Object loop

Tags: powershell, file, move, photo, system.drawing

I am trying to search through all my photo folders and any images with specific dimensions (1125x2436 - i.e. screen captures on iphone) get moved to a seperate folder which I can review and most likely delete after.

I have taken the script from [Writing a script to copy images of certain dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572626/writing-a-script-to-copy-images-of-certain-dimensions) as below. This copies the images, but when I change this to `Move-Item` I get "Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Im guessing because it is still open by System.Drawing.Image in the ForEach-Object loop.

I have tried tweaking this and closing the image before deleting or passing to a variable to use outside the loop but with no success.

This is what I have

```
$source = Get-Location
$destination = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Output\"
$maxWidth    = 1125
$maxHeight   = 2436

# if the destination path does not exist, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

# Add System.Drawing assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # capture the full filename so we can use it in the catch block
    $fileName = $_.FullName
    # Open image file
    try {
        $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($fileName)
        # use '-ge'  if you want to copy files with a width and/or height Greater Or Equal To the max dimensions
        # use '-and' if you want to copy files where both the Width and the Height exceed the max dimensions
        if ($img.Width -eq $maxWidth -and $img.Height -eq $maxHeight) {
    $_ | Move-Item -Verbose -Destination $destination -Force
        }
    } 
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not open file '$fileName' - Not an image file?"
    }
}
```

I should say Im a nood to powershell and posting stackoverflow so any advice greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run just the selection of `$_`? What does it contain?

Comment: I dont know what youre asking me to do sorry. Run it on a seperate line?

Im not even sure what the function of $_ is.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit more digging, it was as simple as adding `$img.dispose()` before the move.

Answered incase useful to anyone else.

Comment: FYI, good you found this. Yet, remember, this is not just about images when using Move-Item, the same thing should have happened using say Remove-Item. This is not a PowerShell issue; it's that Windows cannot move (delete) files are long as filehandles are live. You have to release them first as you've discovered. Even with say Rename-Item, it's a two step process, if in the same folder, depending on naming specifics, or you end calling into core DLLs to avoid that.